# Kotlin json data parsing in fragment

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-fragments

I am quite new to Android. I will have a very critical question. I can extract data from an API, but I want to be able to sort the data I pulled in the same fragment when I am listing it differently.

For example, I am pulling English news from a news API. I want to shoot French news at the same time as if I was just changing the endpoints by pressing a button in the same fragment. Is this possible? Or should I use different fragments for each query type?

Comment: Yes You  can use same fragment with different API call in background

Comment: I got one more question. There is a drawer menu in my project. There are 2 items and 2sides go to different activities. But the same fragments are used in both activities. For example, I want to list the X data when going to activity A, and I want to sort the Y data when clicking the B activity. How can I do it? I can edit the question and show the classes if you can help.

Comment: If you use one fragment to multiple places you need to send bundle variables when you adding fragment in activity.
In fragment based on the bundle parameter our logic should be written.